# How to abort a transaction in rebus?

Tags: c#, rebus

I am struggling when I try to abort a transaction in a message handler. I am using [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/documentation.html).

My goal is to have the following behavior: If a message is received, I try to store its content on the hard disk. If that fails I would like to re-enqueue the message. By doing this I give another instance of the same service the opportunity to try the same.
What I want is basically the possibility to control when a message is `ACK`ed or rejected.

I have looked through the source code, `RabbitMqTransport.cs` in particular and found that when the transaction is committed an `ACK` is sent. If the transaction is aborted, a `NACK` is send. I have once created a wrapper class around RabbitMQ myself and thus know that this is correct.

However it seems that `OnAborted` is never called. Even if I abort the transaction, `OnComitted` is called.

I use the following code to abort the transaction. `context` is the `IMessageContext` instance passed into the `Messagehandler`.

```
context.TransactionContext.OnAborted(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Abort");
});

context.TransactionContext.OnCommitted(async () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Commit");
});

context.TransactionContext.Abort();
```

I also tried different variations of this, like getting the `AmbientTransactionContext` or using the `Rebus.TransactionScope` package, with no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebus is designed to handle ACK/NACK as you would expect, depending on whether your message handler throws an exception or not.

In other words, if your message handler does not throw an exception, the message delivery is considered successful, and the message is ACKed.

If, on the other hand, your message handler throws an exception, the message is NACKed (and thus has its state reset to "Ready" in RabbitMQ terms), effectively making it possible for another instance to grab the message.

However, due to the way the RabbitMQ client driver is designed, I would believe that that message would not actually be returned to the server for other instances to receive – I think (and this is just a guess) that the fact that the driver prefetches messages and stores them in an in-mem queue until they are consumed causes the message to simply be marked internally to be redelivered.

Therefore, I would expect the same service instance to perform all delivery attempts, and then – as you have correctly observed – Rebus will move the message out of the way into an error queue, thus storing it safely to be processed later.

I hope that makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

What is not clear from your post is how you abort the transaction. We use a similar setup with RabbitMq and I always just throw an exception from inside the handler.

Comment: I abort the transaction by getting the `TransactionContext` from the `IMessageContext` passed into the handler and calling abort on it, as shown in my code example. I have also tried just throwing an exception, but that eventually leads Rebus to move the message into the error queue after some time. This happens if for some reason no other instance of the same service is running at that time.

Answer (score 0):

@mookid8000:
Alright, that makes it clear, when messages are `ACK`ed or `NACK`ed.

However I was able to disprove your assumption. I created two consumers in separate console applications binding to the same input queue. One of them always throws an exception. The publisher sends a message every 10 seconds. I can see, that the other consumer processes the message after the faulted throws an exception. I see that, because the message's ID is logged in the console by Rebus.

This answers my question, but does not solve my problem. In my case, what I actually want is the possibility to have the messages remain in the queue, until one of the service instances was able to process it. The reason is that the order of the messages is important. This might be a fundamental error in my approach, but for now I would like not to change that.

Is there a way to prevent (certain) messages to be moved to the error queue? Is the second level retry mechanism in Rebus a possible way to implement this?

See the following source code for further reference:

Normal consumer:

```
class TimeEventHandler : IHandleMessages<TimeEvent>
{
    public async Task Handle(TimeEvent message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message.Time);

        //await Program.Activator.Bus.Reply("Ja danke");
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static BuiltinHandlerActivator Activator;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (Activator = new BuiltinHandlerActivator())
        {
            Activator.Register(() => new TimeEventHandler());

            var bus = Configure
                .With(Activator)
                .Transport(t => t.UseRabbitMq("amqp://guest:guest@192.168.3.50",
                    $"ConsumerPrototype").Prefetch(1))
                .Routing(r => r.TypeBased())
                .Start();

            bus.Subscribe<TimeEvent>();

            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to quit");
            Console.ReadLine();

            // Without the unsubscribe we have a durable subscriber, see http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/DurableSubscription.html
            //bus.Unsubscribe<TimeEvent>();
        }
    }
}
```

Faulted Consumer:

```
class FaultedTimeEventHandler : IHandleMessages<TimeEvent>
{
    public async Task Handle(TimeEvent message)
    {
        throw new Exception("That should not have happened");
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static BuiltinHandlerActivator Activator;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (Activator = new BuiltinHandlerActivator())
        {
            Activator.Register(() => new FaultedTimeEventHandler());

            var bus = Configure
                .With(Activator)
                .Transport(t => t.UseRabbitMq("amqp://guest:guest@192.168.3.50",
                    $"ConsumerPrototype").Prefetch(1))
                .Routing(r => r.TypeBased())
                .Start();

            bus.Subscribe<TimeEvent>();

            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to quit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Publisher:

```
public static class PubSubTest
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting PubSubTest");

        using (var activator = new BuiltinHandlerActivator())
        {
            var bus = Configure
                .With(activator)
                .Transport(t => t.UseRabbitMq("amqp://guest:guest@192.168.3.50", "MessagingTest").Prefetch(1))
                .Routing(r => r.TypeBased())
                .Start();

            Observable
                .Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
                .Subscribe(_ => bus.Publish(new TimeEvent(DateTime.Now)).Wait());

            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to quit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 26.07.17:**
My results with second level retries: After activating them, I handle them by deferring and resending them. By doing this I can at least make sure, that the messages are processed later and not lost.

```
public async Task Handle(IFailed<TimeEvent> failedMessage)
{
    await bus.Defer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), failedMessage.Message);
}
```

This is not an optimal solution:

1. The order of my messages is changed: After a message is delayed, the next message is consumed from the queue.
2. The Timeoutmanager is In-Memory and I do not have access to an SQL-Server.

I read that it is possible to use delayed messages with RabbitMQ. Either you utilize [dead-letter-exchanges](http://yuserinterface.com/dev/2013/01/08/how-to-schedule-delay-messages-with-rabbitmq-using-a-dead-letter-exchange/) or a [plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2015/04/16/scheduling-messages-with-rabbitmq/).

Increasing the maxDeliveryAttempts to `Int32.MaxValue` is very dirty, but does what I want: It keeps the message and most importantly the order of the messages in the queue.

I mark this question as resolved, because the question "How to abort a transaction in Rebus" was answered.